# Autolayout incorrectly positioning subviews when transforming before view is on screen

Tags: ios, uiview, swift, autolayout

I'm attempting to scale the transform of my view before it draws on screen. When I do, however, the view's subviews — that are aligned using auto layout — are misaligned when the view finally appears on screen. Here's what my scaling looks like within `viewDidLoad:`

```
let customView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 568)
self.view.addSubview(customView)
customView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8)
```

If I add the `customView` to my controller's view and wait to transform the view until `viewDidAppear:`, the final rendering is the expected result. However, there is a split second where the view is not scaled.

What do I need to implement in my custom view to allow auto layout to respond to transforms before my view is drawn on screen?

The basic structure of my view is a `UIView` with a `UITextView` as its child. The text view's constraints are pretty straight forward:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[textView]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: ["textView": textView])
NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer:
If I understand your question correctly, you want to override viewDidLayoutSubviews instead of viewDidLoad / viewDidAppear. viewWillAppear will probably work as well.

Longer answer:

viewDidLoad means just that - it's called after the view is loaded, and that is it! Autolayout hasn't run yet, or layoutSubviews for that matter. You should only apply transforms during or after layout has occurred. The earliest time to do that is in viewDidLayoutSubviews. Also, don't forget to call super!